# Android:Having problems with fragmentManager(Error XML inflateExeption)

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments, fragmentmanager

First time I run `onClickMap` function(click button) it works and the `mapFragment` appears, then I click `spotList` button and it works too and the `SpotListFragment` appears, then I run `onClickMap` again and the app crashes!

**Screen Image:**
[image: screenshot]

**MainActivity.class**

```
package com.pap.myspots;

import com.pap.myspots.adapter.TabsPagerAdapter;
import com.pap.myspots.fragments.MapFragment;
import com.pap.myspots.fragments.NotificationsFragment;
import com.pap.myspots.fragments.SpotListFragment;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
        ActionBar.TabListener {

    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
    private ActionBar actionBar;
    String local;
    // Tab titles

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Initilization
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        actionBar = getActionBar();
        mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);    

        // Adding Tabs

            ImageView mapTab = new ImageView(this);
            mapTab.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffbb33"));
            //mapTab.setImageResource(R.drawable.notificationsicon);
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.nicon)
                    .setTabListener(this));
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.micon)
                    .setTabListener(this));
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.sicon)
                    .setTabListener(this));

        /**
         * on swiping the viewpager make respective tab selected
         * */
        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                // on changing the page
                // make respected tab selected
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
            }
        });
    }

    public void clickMap(View v){
        MapFragment mapfragment = new MapFragment();
         getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
         .replace(R.id.frame, mapfragment).commit();
    }

    public void clickList(View v){
        SpotListFragment listfragment = new SpotListFragment();
         getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
         .replace(R.id.frame, listfragment).commit();
    }



    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // on tab selected
        // show respected fragment view
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }

}
```

**fragment_home.xml:**

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#ef4748"
            android:text="Map"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:onClick="clickMap"/>

        <Button 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="List"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:background="#c43c3c"
            android:onClick="clickList"/> 

</LinearLayout>
```

**Error:**

```
E/AndroidRuntime(2971): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(2971): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #46: Error inflating class fragment
E/AndroidRuntime(2971):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
E/AndroidRuntime(2971):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
E/AndroidRuntime(2971):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
E/AndroidRuntime(2971):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
E/AndroidRuntime(2971):     at com.pap.myspots.fragments.MapFragment.onCreateView(MapFragment.java:29)
E/AndroidRuntime(2971):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1500)
E/AndroidRuntime(2971):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:927)
E/AndroidRuntime(2971):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
E/AndroidRuntime(2971):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
E/AndroidRuntime(2971):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1467)
E/AndroidRuntime(2971):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:440)
E/AndroidRuntime(2971):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
E/AndroidRuntime(2971):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
E/AndroidRuntime(2971):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
E/AndroidRuntime(2971):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
E/AndroidRuntime(2971):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(2971):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
E/AndroidRuntime(2971):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
E/AndroidRuntime(2971):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
E/AndroidRuntime(2971):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(2971): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #46: Duplicate id 0x7f05000c, tag null, or parent id 0x0 with another fragment for com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment
E/AndroidRuntime(2971):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:296)
E/AndroidRuntime(2971):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
E/AndroidRuntime(2971):     ... 19 more
```

Comment: Show your full MainActivity class... so reduced to the bones is useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this into your mapFragment.

```
@Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        try {
            SupportMapFragment fragment = (SupportMapFragment) getActivity()
                    .getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
            if (fragment != null)
                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(fragment)
                        .commit();

        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        }
    }
```

you need to destroy the Map fragment properly!

Comment: It worked fine, it just crashed again if i click twice on map button, but i resolved it with an "if clause"

Comment: Ok, so you got the reason of its crashing. GREAT :)